# MSMQ in a real-time system

Tags: c#, .net, xml, msmq

Are there any limitation I should be aware of MSMQ?

I want to use it to read and write messages, but a lot of messages.

The numbers should be around 200,000 - 300,000 in one minute.

Any thoughts? should it work?

Comment: what is the reason you want to use MSMQ?

Comment: Doing a quick performance testing on my (admittedly good, with an SSD) developer machine, on a non-transactional queue, gives me: 30,050 messages/second, or 1,803,055 messages/minute. More than enough for what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSMQ is a queue, where the main benefits are to decouple the sender(s) and the receiver(s) of messages (e.g. receiving system can be offline).

If guaranteed latency is a requirement, then I would look elsewhere (e.g. .NET remoting / WCF NetTCP binding, etc)

That said, we have used MSMQ with low grade hardware with burst rates >> 500 messages per second, but in an integration (EAI) environment, with the benefits of MSMQ being:

- asynchronous - processes which send and receive messages can happen at different rates
- potentially transactional (e.g. under DTC, a message can be put on a queue and updated in a database, under a UOW)
- audited (journalling)
- dead letter queue - i.e. if the receiver never picks up the message after a defined time period.

Low latency was never a requirement - reliability and integrity were the main drivers.

Answer (score 2):

For small, nontransactional messages, this could theoretically be possible, but it's at the upper end of what I've personally heard of.  Stay away from transactional queues, though -- I seriously doubt you'll be able to get that kind of throughput on any realistic platform.

Comment: +1 - a cigarette box calc shows that at a sustained rate 300k messages / minute at 10k / message = 180GB per hour. Not in MSMQ's league.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am about to delete every received message by a service that will run on the MSMQ server

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with this kind of volume in MSMQ because of the dreaded [Insufficient Resources problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/insufficient-resources-run-away-run-away.aspx).

It seems like this would be a rare occurrence, but it happened to me a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article : [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/29/what-are-msmq-s-limits-if-i-had-a-farthing-for-every-time.aspx) It says that MSMQ shouldn't be used as a storage product but used as a transport mechanism.

You could have services that read the messages from the queues and process them in a transactional way. [Here (MSDN link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751493.aspx) you can find some examples. Create a small sample, do some load tests, see if it works.